# how can I replace different characters in a column without using cursor?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
Sample items in table1 

table1.productname 
Moshi Monsters 7-in-1 Accessory Pack - Poppet 
Mario vs. Donkey Kong Mini-Land Mayhem!
```

I would like to `replace` '- . !' from all the `productname` but using

```
select case
        when CHARINDEX ('-',[productname])>0 then REPLACE (ProductName ,'-',' ')
        when CHARINDEX ('!',[productname])>0 then REPLACE (ProductName ,'!','') 
        when CHARINDEX ('.',[productname])>0 then REPLACE (ProductName ,'.','') 
       else productname
       end as productname 
   from table1
```

seems to replace only `-`

```
output

Moshi Monsters 7 in 1 Accessory Pack   Poppet 
Mario vs. Donkey Kong Mini-Land Mayhem 

expected output 
Moshi Monsters 7 in 1 Accessory Pack   Poppet 
Mario vs Donkey Kong MiniLand Mayhem
```

How shall I approach for solution of this, I have multiple characters in the productname to replace such as in example and more and the column is around 5k big. 
actually I wanted to update the table1 with the changed name but wanted to see which are changed and how before I update. It seems all the requirement is not fulfilled with this kind of `replace` statement. 
Seems it could be done with multiple iterations in update but do not know how to use the iteration in update. How shall I process ahead?

Comment: The CASE statement only ever performs 1 of its WHEN/ELSE clauses, namely the first one it finds that applies.  In your sample, since there is a '-' character in your product name, the CASE performs that particular WHEN clause and then stops.  If there were no '-', only then would it check for the '!', and only if there is no '!' will it check for '.'.

Comment: @Hellion       Thanks, so if I remove `CASE` from the statement that must be fine, right? I will try that now and see. like the one said by Marc B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're always using the SAME source for your string replacements: the original `ProductName` field, which does not change. You need to chain the replacements:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ProductName, '.', ''), '!', ''), '-', '')
```

which gets hideously ugly very fast. You'd be better off doing this in your client.

Comment: Thanks, its fast and easier though looks ugly, It is what I was looking for.